# Can not find project web item (ERROR)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts

I am using SmartPart (http://www.codeplex.com/smartpart) to add web parts to SharePoint. When I open the *.ascx file with visual studio it doesn't display the design of the control showing the error however it runs well when it is added to share point. But I need to see the design to be able to add controls through tool box visually not with code.

Comment: Do you have any details on what the error is?

Comment: It says Can not find project web item and does not display the control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is How you need to make it open. Create a Normal ASP.NET Web Application. Place the User Control (the control you are using in the SmartPart to display) in it. Add all the Reference it might need. Then You will be able to Open the User Control and edit. Later you need to copy that user control from Web Application and use it as needed .